# What is the best way to evaluate all occurrences of a field within a list in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, list

I am new to VB.NET and I keep telling myself there **must** be a better way to do what I need to do several times a day which is look into a `list` and see if that one field is set to `true` anywhere in that list.

So far, I've been using the `For Each` statement:

```
For Each player In ListOfPlayers  
  If player.isActive Then  
    ... do something ...  
  End If
Next
```

But I know some of the other languages can do something like:

```
if ListOfPlayers(*).isActive == true
```

which just seems more concise and to the point. Any suggestion?

Comment: You could use LINQ, but that's .NET 3.0+ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by Bobby in the comments, use LINQ:

```
If ListOfPlayers.Any(Function (p) p.IsActive) Then …
```

This asks whether there’s *any* player (`Any`) for which `IsActive` is `True`.